# Trying to change the position of my logo in the navigation bar when switching to 'mobile view' and navigation bar becomes a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, show-hide, navigationbar

I am fairly new to coding and am trying to create a navigation bar with a couple of different abilities.
  My navigation bar currently has:
   -a logo
   -menu items 
   -drop down menu (when in mobile view)

### PROBLEM:

When my click to display the drop down menu, the logo that is still being displayed creates an open space between the bottom of the logo and the menu starting right below it.

### WANTED SOLUTION:

I want to create a script of some sort that will HIDE the logo when I click on the menu icon to display the drop down menu items.

So does anyone know of a way to create a simple js or css where I can have the logo hide when the drop down menu is displayed? 
   So all I need is a simple code for:

***click on menu icon*** = logo disappears & drop down menu is displayed

***unclick on menu icon*** = logo reappears & drop down menu is not displayed

Here is my code so far..... (also please feel free to tell me if I have any unnecessary extra code that I do not need. I am open to all suggestions)

https://jsfiddle.net/beginnercoder/4orac61e/#&togetherjs=mCK2aymdrJ

or code is below

---

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="An example of a fixed-position(sticky) top navigation bar that remains visible while the user scrolls the page.">
    <meta name="author" content="Six Revisions">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fixed-navigation-bar.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/nav-bar.js">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/website%20logo.png">

   <div id="container"> </div>
   <head>
   <nav class="fixed-nav-bar">
   <div id="menu" class="menu">
   <img src="Images/website%20logo.png" id="logo"> 

   <a class="show" href="#menu">Menu</a><a class="hide" href="#hidemenu">Menu</a>
  <ul class="menu-items">
  <li><a href="//sixrevisions.com"><h4>Home</h4></a></li>
  <li><a href="//sixrevisions.com/about/"><h4>About</h4></a></li>
  <li><a href="//sixrevisions.com/contact/"><h4>Contact</h4></a></li>
  <li><a href="//twitter.com/sixrevisions"><h4>Twitter</h4></a></li>
  <li><a href="//www.facebook.com/sixrevisions"><h4>Facebook</h4></a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="content">
  <div class="description">
  <h1>Fixed Navigation Bar</h1>
  <p class="summary">*/ text*/ </p>
  <a class="button" href="//sixrevisions.com/css/fixed-navigation-bar/">Read the tutorial</a>
  <a class="button" href="//github.com/sixrevisions/fixed-navigation-bar">View Source on GitHub</a>
  </div>
  </section>
  <p><a class="button-dark" href="//sixrevisions.com/css/fixed-navigation-bar/">Read the tutorial</a>
  <a class="button-dark" href="//github.com/sixrevisions/fixed-navigation-bar">View Source on GitHub</a></p>
  <body>

  <p> Wayfarers portland shabby chic, vegan jianbing helvetica vice craft beer poutine pork belly mustache roof party. Whatever kitsch etsy, air plant dreamcatcher shabby chic thundercats literally kinfolk tousled. Hot chicken enamel pin lumbersexual, pour-over la croix franzen salvia tousled pok pok green juice beard snackwave. Yuccie messenger bag cornhole, fam austin master cleanse iceland helvetica kinfolk sartorial raw denim fap mustache pinterest retro. Gluten-free umami ugh tumeric. Shabby chic enamel pin vaporware, hella retro wayfarers affogato vice lo-fi man bun hashtag pug messenger bag. Distillery YOLO vexillologist bicycle rights, typewriter butcher vinyl unicorn helvetica vape mixtape kitsch listicle.
  </p> 
  <p>Tofu vaporware portland pour-over keytar, tilde pug distillery. Kogi paleo tousled skateboard sartorial hexagon fashion axe blue bottle cronut. Asymmetrical ennui portland, +1 tilde listicle authentic cardigan scenester keytar vexillologist organic poutine. Intelligentsia aesthetic artisan keytar, helvetica kinfolk hella ramps tilde viral stumptown occupy lumbersexual tousled marfa. Trust fund sriracha kickstarter, activated charcoal meh bushwick ennui franzen bicycle rights edison bulb literally offal skateboard. Hexagon fap disrupt scenester. Keytar flexitarian listicle affogato kinfolk vexillologist af art party, cold-pressed offal hell of fingerstache chambray sartorial.</p> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

---

CSS:

```
    .fixed-nav-bar {position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow:visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #698e8c;}

    .content {
    margin-top: 20px;}


    .fixed-nav-bar li, .fixed-nav-bar a { 
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;}

    #logo { padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    max-height: 90px;
    min-width: 97px; 
    margin-left: clear;
    margin-right:20px;}

    .menu {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;}

    .menu a, .menu a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;}

    .menu a:hover, .menu a:target {
    color: #ebebeb;}

    .menu-items { display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align: text-bottom;}

    .sitename {
    min-height: 190;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;}

    a.sitename, a:visited.sitename {
    color: #e0e0e0;}

    .menu-items li { overflow: visible; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;}

    .menu-items a {
    text-decoration: none;}

    .show, .hide {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left;
    color: #dde1e2;}

    .show {
    background-image: url(assets/down-arrow-icon.png);}

    .hide {
    background-image: url(assets/up-arrow-icon.png);}

    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    #logo { 
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:110px;
    height:220px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    margin-left: 0;}

   .menu { 
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;}

  .sitename {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 15px;
  margin-left: 0px;}

  .menu-items {
  display: none; 
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:0px; 
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  background-color: #698e8c;}

  .menu-items li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;}

  .show, .hide {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;}

  .show {
  display: inline-block; }

  .hide {
  display: none;}

  #menu:target .show {
  display: none;}

  #menu:target .hide, #menu:target .menu-items {
  display: inline-block; }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .sitename, .show, .hide {
  font-size: 14px;}
  #logo {display: fixed;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:110px;
  height:220px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left: 0;}
  }
```

Thank you so much in advance!

-beginnercoder

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle.

Comment: Hi Sayan,  Yes I just made one: https://jsfiddle.net/beginnercoder/4orac61e/#&togetherjs=mCK2aymdrJ

Answer (score 0):

Its quite difficult to edit your code, cause you use two two menu, one for 'show' and one for 'hide', its not a right procedure.
For now I'm giving you the concept, Hope it helps.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#logo').toggle('show');
        });
    });
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#hideshow{
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id='logo'>Here's your logo</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='Menu'>
</div>
```

Comment: So unfortunately still a little bit confused on this... I would want the logo to hide when I click on the menu bar, and also when the menu bar is clicked, it has a drop down of menu items that appear.